# airflow initdb has issue with oracle database

Tags: oracle, airflow

I am facing issue while initializing the airflow database using oracle.

1. ORA-00910: specified length too long its datatype. Oracle supports 4000 byte length but
   connection table column extra and chart table column default_params required 5000 char as Varchar2.

2.ORA_2285: invalid modification of columns during the below query which is not supported by oracle.
[SQL: ALTER TABLE xcom MODIFY value BLOB]

Can anyone please let me know the solution. Also please comment if you faced the similar issue.

Comment: Is this resolved? I'm also getting the same - would be really appreciated if we get the solution for this :)

Comment: I got information that Apache Airflow does not support Oracle as a database. You can use MySQL to get it working.